# Cannot access LAN resources when connected via wireless

Tags: router, wireless-networking, lan

My ISP provided a BEC 7800 TN R2 router with wireless capability for my home. I have a Windows desktop computer connected via Ethernet cable to the router. I have no problems with my desktop computer. I also have a Windows laptop. Both are running Windows 7.

When I connect my laptop **via Ethernet cable**, I can...

- Connect to the Internet
- Connect to router admin page
- Ping the desktop computer
- Access the desktop computer's shared drive
- Remote Desktop Connection to the desktop using either its Windows name or IP address.
- Print to the network-connected printer

When I connect my laptop to the router **via wireless**, I can..

- Connect to the Internet
- Connect to router admin page
- (but nothing else)

I would like to access LAN resources (desktop computer and printer) when connected wirelessly.

The wireless page on the router, looks like this:

[image]

You can see that my router supports "Client Isolation." However, I do not have that feature enabled. Just for testing, I enabled it. It made no difference. I disabled it again. No difference.

When I connect my laptop **via Ethernet cable**, I get...

```
ipconfig

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : RanDSLV.gateway
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::396e:db30:d39e:cea0%11
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.50.58
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.50.254

tracert 192.168.50.70

Tracing route to Abednego [192.168.50.70] (the desktop computer)
over a maximum of 30 hops:
1     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  Abednego [192.168.50.70]
Trace complete.

route print

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   192.168.50.254    192.168.50.58     20
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     192.168.50.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.50.58    276
    192.168.50.58  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.50.58    276
   192.168.50.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.50.58    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.50.58    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.50.58    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

When I connect my laptop to the router **via wireless**, I get..

```
ipconfig

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : RanDSLV.gateway
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d4b3:cc8a:b4d9:1944%10
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.50.59
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.50.254

tracert 192.168.50.70

Tracing route to Abednego [192.168.50.70] over a maximum of 30 hops:
1  Mishael.RanDSLV.gateway [192.168.50.59]  reports: Destination host unreachable.
Trace complete.

route print

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   192.168.50.254    192.168.50.59     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     192.168.50.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.50.59    281
    192.168.50.59  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.50.59    281
   192.168.50.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.50.59    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.50.59    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.50.59    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

With regard to Windows networking, both networks are set as "Home networks."

[image: Windows networking options]

**Question**: Can you suggest what configuration change I need to make so that I can access LAN resources when connected wirelessly?

Comment: Off hand I don't think its your router. Is one network connection set as public, and the other as home/office?

Comment: It has been over three years. And this is still a problem. Would love to know what to change in my wireless router to access network resources.

Comment: I wonder if there is such a configuration where you have to VLAN the wireless to the LAN. The router seems fairly comprehensive - allowing both multiple ethernet LAN segments and multiple wireless networks (SSIDs) - so I wonder if you need to dive into any LAN VLAN settings - not WAN VLAN. I.e. How does SSID1 know it can talk to Ethernet VLAN1, how does SSID2 know it, too, may also be able to talk to Ethernet VLAN1 etc. A similiar manufacturer (with similar looking interface) is DrayTek... you have to enable inter-VLAN communication by means of a series of tick boxes - E.g. SSID1 and VLAN1

Comment: @Kinnectus Great suggestion. However, I cannot try it since we have upgraded our bandwidth and router. My new router does not have this issue.

Comment: if you have replaced your equipment and the question is no longer valid, can you write yourself an answer and then mark it is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted the original question four years ago. In the eight years that we owned the router, I never was able to find a solution. Last week, we replaced the router and the new router worked perfectly without any special configuration changes.

One possible workaround was suggested yesterday by @Kinnectus, "...a configuration where you have to VLAN the wireless to the LAN." That may work, but I cannot try it any longer since we upgraded.

My conclusion is that it was a shortcoming of that old router. The solution for us was to replace the router.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem on my new router was to disable "Port Isolation" which was located in the "Security" settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your lan settings *look* correct, and I think we can rule that out. I've been bitten by something *else* that might be your issue in the past - your 'network type'

Windows file sharing tends to get shut down if you're on a 'public' network - my guess is your network profile is set as such.

[image]

Not the *best* example, but the network above should have full access to lan resources. The one below shouldn't. It makes sense to create a new wifi network as a public one. Simply click on the blue underlined network type, and switch it over to home and see if it works

Comment: Great suggestion. But, both my Local Area Network and Wireless Network Connection display as "Home network." I'm still stumped.

Comment: Next thing I'd do is check sharing settings. Do you have the same issues between wired and wireless networks on any other system, or is it isolated to this one?

Comment: I was able to test with an iPad and a [ping app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ping-network-reachability/id576773404). The iPad ping app indicates timeouts when trying to ping the desktop computer through the wireless on the router. I temporarily connected a wireless access point to the router via Ethernet. When the iPad connects to the second wireless, it *can* ping the desktop computer. This tells me it is the router, not Windows sharing. But, I'm open to more suggestions!

Comment: @Wally - Granted this is an old post and i came across it as i'm facing a similar issue. Were you able to resolve it? If so, what was the resolution?

Comment: @motivated  I never solved this problem. We are still just living with it. Would love for a solution to come along.

Comment: @Wally - i'll keep you posted if i'm able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to set up the wireless router as an access point.

Check the user manual, or http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/36406-43-convert-wireless-router-wireless-access-point

Let me know how it works.

Comment: I think the idea that one can "set up the wireless router as an access point" applies when you have *two* wireless routers. In my case, I am using a single wireless router.