# Wifi Name Resolution on Windows network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, dns, lan

I'm running several windows laptops/computers (7 and above) and a server on a LAN. When I connect via LAN cable, all computers are able to access network shares, team viewer, etc. However, if any laptop is on wifi, it is not accessible on the network.

I dug a bit and found the issue is with name resolution. From the laptop on wifi, I can ping the other using IP addresses but not via their LAN names.

All computers are hooked to Cisco Router with DHCP. All IPs are assigned dynamically.

What is the solution so that I get Wifi to work the same way as a LAN cable?

Comment: What is acting as your wireless router? Is that box doing NAT?

Comment: Cisco wifi Router WAG54G2

Answer (score 1):

It helps if you give exact configuration details, router config files, IP settings computers etc. (I can't comment so I had to put this in answer).

Did you compare the settings of your computer/notebook's ethernet (lan) and wifi network adapter? 
For example look at Ip settings and check for 'client for microsoft network'
Are these different  If yes correct Wifi adapter IP settings.

Check Home/Public homegroup etc.

Check also if Router setting restrictions exists for connection via WIFI.

See also [Cannot access LAN resources when connected via wireless](https://superuser.com/questions/805940/cannot-access-lan-resources-when-connected-via-wireless)