# Cannot access printer while connected over eth but able over wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printing, printer

I have a HP laserjet printer, its connected over wifi to a router. My PC is connected to the same router over eth.

- When i try to install printer while connected over eth, printer is visible (via ping) and HP smart recognizes it but returns "printer is off error"

Meanwhile if I am connect thru a wifi adapter to wifi, everything works as intended.

The router is a ZTE , i never had such an issue before with the printer on other routers so I am suspecting it's the cause. The router is new.
I have disabled all possible firewalls + Wi-Fi isn't isolated. I don't have more ideas.

Comment: Connect the Printer to your local LAN and put the driver on all computers and then it should work. Make sure (sure) that you are working on ONE subnet.

Comment: Also double-check that you have the correct port configuration selected.  Reserve an IP address for the printer, and add a new port (through printer properties) configuration using TCP/IP > Raw > and enter the printer's IP address.  Hit okay and double check that the new port is toggled on.  For the driver, select the PCL6 version without the bloatware for your model LaserJet.

Comment: Hello I had this problems years ago, it was a router issue/settings. For some reason devices on ethernet could not see devices on wifi, only ethernet devices could see other ethernet devices, the same for wifi. This question seems relevant to your problem https://superuser.com/questions/805940/cannot-access-lan-resources-when-connected-via-wireless

Comment: Check if you have an option WIFI isolatiom in your router settings and make sure its off.